# tor stops while bootstrapping, what could be the problem?

Tags: 10.04, networking, internet, proxy, tor

since last week I am having a problem using tor. It says bootstrapped 10%  finishing handshake with directory server and then it just stops. It might help to say that I am in Iran. Any idea how to solve it? Thanks.

Comment: according to a blog on the tor website, it depends on your isp: https://blog.torproject.org/blog/update-internet-censorship-iran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tor maverick repository is up...that could be related, I just reinstalled tor from repo.  Being in Iran, it might be that you need a bridge that isn't on your nation's blocklist.  Just a couple of pieces of pertinent info.

Comment: note: when in locales that are "more restrictive than most" it might be useful to have a VPS provider that allows you to run a VPN service on 443 such that you can bounce off of an "unlisted" host into the tor network...again just thoughts.

Comment: last comment and I'll stop...there are other individuals that I have helped in your geographic vicinity.  I am thinking that tor nodes are blocked.  Again, the non-blacklisted bridges or VPS with proxy services running.  Not just thoughts.

Comment: thanks aking1012 , I thought so too because I can not get tor working on windows either , I added bridges too and still no luck thanks again